# UK ILR rule for switching from Tier 2 general to Tier 2 dependant

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, immigration

I have been in UK for past 2 years on Tier 2 general visa. But now I am planning to switch to my wife's dependent who is also on Tier 2 general.

If I switch now, will I be eligible for applying ILR in another 3 years or do I have to stay for 5 more years to become eligible?